# Zip Code Validatior not working in angular reactive form validator patten

Tags: angular

```
  'zip': [null, {validators: [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$')]}],
```

eg: 12345 or 12345-3456

It is working for 12345 but not working for 12345-3456

Answer (score 0):

try below code accepting '-' also as a count

```
^[0-9-]{5,10}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$

{5,10} => accepts min length 5 and max-length 7 you can change accordingly

 'zip': [null, {validators: [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9-]{5,7}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$')]}],


  12345        //output - true
  12345-3456   //output - true
  1234         //output - false
```